# How to keep log / keep record of one particular Process

Tags: windows, process, perfmon

In my Task Manager, there is one process (.exe)

I want to keep log or keep record of that process i.e how much cpu % it is utilizing for a particular time \ Day.

for example :- abc.exe process

Can you suggest, how to do ?

can we have a log through perfmon.msc ?

Thanks & Regards,

Param

Answer (score 0):

Read the 2 minute drill on *logman* http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/13/two-minute-drill-logman-exe.aspx

Basically you can use *logman* to create a *data collector*                                                                           associated with a set of perfmon counters to capture.

To review your results you can open the blg file as indicated here
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/a7bfb9dc-f845-4138-b603-ee1da3d04f2e/